# Verify if a Job will fit in a cluster before launching it

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have an application that will start Jobs in different K8S cluster/cloud provider depending of different criteria, including the current availability of the cluster.
In other word, my application will loop over acceptable K8S clusters, and if a cluster is currently full, the job can be launched in a different cluster.

My problem is, how to determine that the Job will fit or not in the cluster.
My first idea was to loop over all nodes, and see how many have enough resources (Mem/CPU) to run my job.

While doable, it seems there is no native API to get used resources for one specific node. I can code that, but this gives me the feeling this is not the right solution, as it seems to be redoing part of the kube scheduler, and I am sure there are lot of edge case to be taken in account.

Maybe I am overthinking this, and this totally the right path, but I wanted to check if there was not cleaner solution.

Comment: Seems to me like you are trying to solve the halting problem :')

Answer (score 1):

You can use [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) which exposes a metrics api that you could query.

With that you have [node metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/node-metrics.md) like `kube_node_status_allocatable` or `kube_node_status_capacity` and [pod metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md) like `kube_pod_container_resource_requests` or `kube_pod_container_resource_limits`.

Comment: Thanks for the metric API, it helps ! That being said, I may be missing something, but it stays a bit complex: I need list all nodes to get capacity, then list all pods, filter the one running on the specific node I want, extract resource request and actual usage from all containers, and compare it to my node. 
I might be too naive, but I was expecting to have API returning the usage including the resource request directly out of a node.